# Stack Trace Window in NHProfiler not show source code

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhprof

I've been using NHProf for awhile and I've found it really useful but I haven't been able to get the Stack Trace window to work like I've seen in a tekpub video were it showed the line and file of the source code making the nhibernate seession request.

my nhibernate sesssion setup is

```
private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
        sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()                        
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=nhibernate;User ID=sa;Password=*****;Pooling=False")) 
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Make>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread_static"))
            .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("generate_statistic", "true"))                        .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Is there some other configuration set I should be make to get this feature to work?

Answer (score 0):

It should just work.
Can you open a question about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/nhprof), with a small project that reproduce that issue?